# Does Jasmine's spyOn() allow the spied on function to be executed?

Tags: unit-testing, jasmine

Does Jasmine's `spyOn()` method allow the spied on function to be executed, or does it, kind of - intercept the invocation when the spied method is (about to get) invoked, and returns `true`.

PS: Could anyone point me to the explanation of `spyOn()`'s inner workings?

Comment: check out `.and.callThrough()` or `andCallThrough()` depending on your jasmine version.  I'm not an expert on the matter but i believe it intercepts the functionality which is why the and call through is available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spy :

**A spy can pretend to be a function or an object that you can use while writing unit test code to examine behavior of functions/objects**

```
var Person = function() {};
Dictionary.prototype.FirstName = function() {
return "My FirstName";
};
Dictionary.prototype.LastName = function() {
return "My LastName";
};
Person.prototype.MyName = function() {
return FirstName() + " " + LastName();
};

Person.prototype.MyLocation = function() {
Return ”some location”;
};

describe("Person", function() {
    it('uses First Name and Last Name for MyName', function() {
        var person = new Person;
        spyOn(person , "FirstName"); 
        spyOn(person, "LastName"); 
        person.MyName();
        expect(person.FirstName).toHaveBeenCalled(); 
        expect(person.LastName).toHaveBeenCalled(); 
    });
});
```

**Through SpyOn you can know whether some function has been / has not been called**

```
expect(person. MyLocation).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
```

**You can ensure that a spy always returns a given value and test it**

```
spyOn(person, " MyName ").andReturn("My FirstNameMy LasttName ");
var result = person.MyName();
expect(result).toEqual("My FirstName  My LasttName ");
```

**Spies can call through to a fake function**

```
it("can call a fake function", function() {
var fakeFun = function() {
alert("I am a spy!”);
return "hello";
};
var person = new person();
spyOn(person, "MyName").andCallFake(fakeFun);
person. MyName (); // alert
})
```

**You can even create a NEW spy function or object and make use of it**

```
it("can have a spy function", function() {
var person = new Person();
person.StreetAddress = jasmine.createSpy("Some Address");
person. StreetAddress ();
expect(person. StreetAddress).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Comment: Thank you for an extensive answer.

Answer (score 1):

It just creates a mock(spy) object and injects it to your tested code.

It has three main purposes:

1. Testing your code if it calls spy: *toHaveBeenCalled*
2. Testing your code if it calls with appropriate parameters: *toHaveBeenCalledWith*
3. Testing your code for different return values from spy: *and.callThrough*