# How to mock or callFake a basic javascript function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I've two functions funcA() and funcB(), I'm writing unit test cases for $scope.funcA().

Below is the the definition:

```
function funcB(){
//statements
 console.log("At function B");
};

$scope.funcA() = function(){
funcB(); 
console.log("At function A");
};
```

Right now while I'm testing my $scope.funcA() is actually calling my funcB(). How to stop this and make a fake call or mock to funcB(); in Jasmine.

Comment: You can't. The function has to be accessible in order for you to spy on it. As it is, your `funcB` is only accessible from inside the controller. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22921570/2759075)

Comment: @yarons Hi so what is the right way to do this, should I make my funcB() like $scope.funcB(){}, so that I'm able to test it ?

Comment: I don't know of any other way to do that

Answer (score 0):

you can use `spyOn()` and `andCallFake()` to achieve it.
see one of my earlier answer here . 
[Does Jasmine's spyOn() allow the spied on function to be executed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26912534/does-jasmines-spyon-allow-the-spied-on-function-to-be-executed/26913552#26913552)

hope this helps.

**EDIT**

for newer versions of jasmine, the snytax would be

```
spyOn($scope, 'funcB').and.callFake(function() {
      return 'something';
});
```

for a complete list, see - http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html

Comment: Hi could you show me  a demo on my given example in my question, I've already tried alot I'll be glad if you can show me this with my example.

Comment: you should create a plunk/jsfiddle

Comment: see funcB is just a basic javascript function i.e.,
    function funcB(){
    //statements
    }
_Now what i did is this_
    var mockfuncB = jasmine.createSpy("funcB");
        spyOn(mockfuncB, 'funcB').and.callFake(function(){ 
    });
what i want to do is i want to make a fake call to funcB() from funcA().
_but it is showing error that funcB() method does not exist_